# How to get message from an ads with facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-ads-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I have an Ad ID, I query the creative fields and I got the creative ID. I then make another API call to get the object_story_spec, if theres no data, I found out that I have to make a query the other field, effective_object_story_id. The issue here is that when I query the resulting id that I got, which is an organic post ID from the account page, I got this

```
    {
  "message": "{{product.brand}}",
    }
```

Which I suspect is because theres a dynamic ads thing. Is there a way to sidestep this issue? What Im trying to do is to fetch the message associated with an ads, but the methods that I used seems too complicated.

Comment: Have you found any solution this?